# SQLDeveloper query automatic padding CHAR field

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Given the table `ATABLE` with a field `AFIELD` of type `CHAR(8)`, and where i have a field with value `"1234567 "`

Why, in SQL Developer, if I query:

```
SELECT * FROM ATABLE WHERE AFIELD = '1234567';
```

It will automatically pad the missing space and return the results, and if I query with :

```
SELECT * FROM ATABLE WHERE AFIELD = :value;
```

and input the value, it wont ?

Comment: The real question is: why are you using a `char` column? A `varchar2` is always a better choice (the problem you have is just another example on why `char` should not be used)

Comment: How did you declare the `value` bind variable? I'm guessing `var value varchar2(8)` rather than as `char(8)` if you're seeing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00220):

> Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the data type CHAR by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics.

When you do `WHERE AFIELD = '1234567'` the text literal `'1234567'` is treated as `char` and [blank-padded comparison semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements002.htm#BABJBDGB) are used to compare the column value and the literal. Even though the literal doesn't have the trailing space, those semantics see them as the same, so it finds a match.

When you use a bind variable the literal you assign to it is a `char`, but the bind variable itself is `varchar2` - even if you declare it as `char`, oddly, though in that case the value is blank-padded anyway:

```
var char_value char(8);
exec :char_value := '1234567';
var varchar2_value varchar2(8);
exec :varchar2_value := '1234567';

select dump('1234567') as d1, dump(:char_value) as d2, dump(:varchar2_value) as d3
from dual;

D1                                   D2                                   D3                                  
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=7: 49,50,51,52,53,54,55   Typ=1 Len=8: 49,50,51,52,53,54,55,32 Typ=1 Len=7: 49,50,51,52,53,54,55
```

The text literal is [data type 96 (`char`)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr06002.htm#SQLQR959), while both bind variables are type 1 (`varchar`/`varchar2`); but notice the `char_value` bind variable has the trailing space, with length 8 and the last character as code point 32.

When you compare your `char` column value with a `varchar2` bind variable the column value is [implicitly converted](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51047)  from `char` to `varchar2`:

> The following rules govern implicit data type conversions:
>
> - During SELECT FROM operations, Oracle converts the data from the column to the type of the target variable.

So your space-padded `char(8)` column value is implicitly converted to `varchar2(8)` to match the bind variable's data type, and then because they are `varchar2` the nonpadded comparison semantics are used.

When you compare your `char(8)` column with the supposedly-`char(8)` bind variable, you're actually comparing with a padded `varchar2(8)` - but both the implicitly converted column value and the blank-padded bind variable are actually the same, both with the trailing space; `'1234567 '` is the same as `'1234567 '`, so there is a match, even with nonpadded comparison semantics.

With the `varchar2(8)` bind variable the same thing happens, but now the bound value is *not* padded, and as you are using nonpadded comparison semantics to compare `'1234567 '` with `'1234567'` - they are not the same, so there is no match, and no data is returned by the query.

---

As @a_horse_with_no_name said you should almost always use `varchar2` rather than `char`. But if you must use it and are stuck with it then at least make sure you use the same data type for comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You are right

```
SELECT * FROM ATABLE WHERE AFIELD = :value;
```

does not work with CHAR as you desire.

Anyway I have noticed that the following query works as you desire:

```
SELECT * FROM ATABLE WHERE AFIELD = &value;
```

If you use &value in several places, you can use &&value (double &) the first time (and &value elsewhere),
in order to avoid to input the same value several times;
when you have to change that value, you can undefine it with:

```
undef value;
```

Comment: surely, if afield is a string field, it should be `where afield = '&value'`?

Comment: In my test, both SqlDeveloper and SQL*Plus on db xe 11g, quotation mark (') was not necessary; I remember that, in the past, in some circumstances I was obliged to use '', not in this case.

Comment: really? Because in SQL*Plus (11.2.0.4), when I do `define x=X` and then run `select * from dual where dummy = &x;` I get `ORA-00904: "X": invalid identifier`. It works if I do `select * from dual where dummy ='&x';` though. And, if I do `undefine x` and then run `select * from dual where dummy = &x;`, it works if I type 'X' when prompted. So you must be adding the single-quotes to the value when prompted?